# How I can fix this problem when print string in C?

Tags: c, initialization, printf, undefined-behavior, c-strings

I  have problem with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 100

int main()
{
    char s1[size],s2[size],s3[size];
    int i,j,k,p;
    
    printf("s1: ");fgets(s1,size,stdin);
    printf("s2: ");fgets(s2,size,stdin);
    if (s1[strlen(s1)-1]=='\n')
        s1[strlen(s1)-1]='\0';
    if (s2[strlen(s1)-1]=='\n')
        s2[strlen(s2)-1]='\0';
    printf("Insert position: ");scanf("%d",&p);
    j=0;
    for (i=p;i<strlen(s1);i++)
    {
        s4[j]=s1[i];
        j++;
    }
    printf("s3: %s\n", s3); 
}
```

When I run this file. This have wrong result. I don't know why s3 is 'a'. Anyone can help me. Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: You don't put anything in s3, so it could contain any old junk.

Comment: Please enable your compiler's warnings (`gcc -Wall new1.c`). Gcc happily notes `variable 's4' set but not used` for your code, which should be clue enough that something is wrong.

Comment: I think s3 contain "\0".

Comment: Why would it contain \0? You don't assign it there and C doesn't initialize variables unless you ask it to.

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve], which solves many problems already!

Comment: It's a big exercise, but I don't understand the result 'a'. The variable 's4' I will use in code below. So I will erase s4 if you think it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you are filling the character array `s4`.

```
for (i=p;i<strlen(s1);i++)
{
    s4[j]=s1[i];
    j++;
}
```

But are outputting the character array `s3`

```
printf("s3: %s\n", s3);
```

that as and the array `s4` does not contain a string.:) The array `s3` is not initialized and contains indeterminate values.

You need to write at least like

```
j=0;
for ( size_t n = strlen( s1 ); i < n; i++ )
{
    s3[j]=s1[i];
    j++;
}

s3[j] = '\0';

printf("s3: %s\n", s3);
```

Comment: Actually, I will print s4 below (this is a big exercise) and the result of s4 is right, but when I check s3. I don't understand why the result is 'a'.

Comment: @VanLeThanh You did not fill the array s3. So what is unclear? Moreover as I wrote in the answer if you are using the conversion specifier %s then the array shall contain a string.

Comment: so, when I declare an string (eg: char s3[100]). I think it's a null string and it will have character "\0".

Comment: @VanLeThanh Objects with automatic storage duration that is that are declared in a block scope are not initialized and have indeterminate values. If you declared the array in a file scope then it indeed would be initialized by zeroes.

Comment: Oh yeah. So when we declare a string. It's may be have a random character in string?

Comment: @VanLeThanh When you declare an array within a function body without the storage specifier static it has indeterminate values.

Comment: @VanLeThanh You could declare the array like char s3[size] = "";

Comment: Yes, Now, I understand your comment. Thank you very much for your help. I will know more about language C (I'm new student in C).

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared s4 but you are using s4 instead of s3. And also printing s4.

```
s4[j]=s1[i];
```

Do this

```
s3[j] = s1[i];
```

Output:

```
s1: hello
s2: wo
Insert position: 3
s3: lo
```